# How to access child ngModel reference in directive link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, color-picker

I'm using bootstrap-colorpicker in combination with an angular directive.

Inside my form is colorpicker which I want to watch for changes.
As the value of the colorpicker is updated by this colorpicker jQuery plugin this does not work. I understand I have to implement this in my directive but can't figure out how.

Inside my  I have the following markup:

```
<div data-colorpicker class="input-group colorpicker-element">
    <input id="background" type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="myModel.background" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

This markup is needed by bootstrap-colorpicker. Note I added data-colorpicker directive which initializes the colorpicker with:

```
myDirectives.directive('colorpicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.colorpicker();
        }
    };
});
```

So far so good. Note that the colorpicker is hooked up on wrapping div, which I thin kis causing my problem.

I extended the code to something like:

```
myDirectives.directive('colorpicker', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require : '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          element.colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(ev.color.toHex());
              });
          });
      }
  };
});
```

but the problem is the ngModel is defined on the input and not on the wrapping div.

Can I access the child scope/ngModel?

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to wrap all the html in a directive.

The template:

```
<div class="input-group colorpicker-element">
    <input id="background" type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="ngModel" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

Directive code:

```
myDirectives.directive('colorpicker', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require : '?ngModel',
      scope: {
          'ngModel': '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          element.colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(ev.color.toHex());
              });
          });
      },
      templateUrl: '/partials/colorpicker.html'
  };
});
```

Then you can use it in controller:

```
<colorpicker ng-model="myModel.background" />
```

Comment: It won't work at least because (1) directive name "colorpicker" doesn't match anything in the html and (2) the 4th attribute of `link()` function is an array of controllers.

Comment: @Stalinko Actually, the 4th attribute is an array if you make it one, when you declare
`require: ['myCtrl1', 'myCtrl2']` then you will get an array, however, the way is shown in this example you will only get the controller being asked for.